# Как разбить строку по однаковым символам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть строка

```
 hhhrrrraaavvvvvvvaaaa
```

Как из неё получить список?

```
['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv','aaaa']
```

Answer (score 7):

```
from itertools import groupby

items = [''.join(v) for k, v in groupby('hhhrrrraaavvvvvvv')]
```

Comment: Ваш вариант с генератором списка чище, что-то затупил с своим циклом :)

Comment: @gil9red разнообразие ответов - это хорошо :)

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'hhhrrrraaavvvvvvv'
items = []

for _, sub in groupby(text):
    items.append(''.join(sub))

print(items)  # ['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv']
```

---

Вариант с [регуляркой](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

text = 'hhhrrrraaavvvvvvv'

items = [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'(.)\1+', text)]
print(items)  # ['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv']
```

Comment: большое спасибо, тоже думал, что можно использовать groupby, но опыта не хватает, чтобы понять как работает этот метод) буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

Пример без `groupby`, определяем индексы смены букв, подсаживаем туда `"@"` и затем `split` по подсаженному:

```
print(''.join([t[x]+"@" if not t[x] == t[x+1] else t[x] for x in range(len(t)-1)] + [t[-1]]).split("@"))
# ['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv', 'aaaa']
# t = 'hhhrrrraaavvvvvvvaaaab'
# ['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv', 'aaaa', 'b']
# t = 'hhhrrrraaavvvvvvvaaaabb'
# ['hhh', 'rrrr', 'aaa', 'vvvvvvv', 'aaaa', 'bb']
```

Избавился от повторного прохождения по последовательности ценой отдельного добавления последнего символа

Comment: А можно рядом тот же алгоритм, но разбитый на составляющие? :)

Comment: я там упростил выражение - теперь "по-чище"